# Writing variables to file with bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to configure a file with a bash script. And the variables in the bash script are not written in file as it is written in script.

Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s" "template("$DATE\t$HOST\t$PRIORITY\t$MSG\n")" >> /file.txt

exit 0
```

This results to template('tttn') instead of template("$DATE\t$HOST\t$PRIORITY\t$MSG\n in file.

How do I write in the script so that the result is template("$DATE\t$HOST\t$PRIORITY\t$MSG\n in the configured file?

Is it possible to write variable as it looks in script to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the strings you want to write within single quotes to avoid variable replacement.

```
> FOO=bar
> echo "$FOO"
bar
> echo '$FOO'
$FOO
>
```

Comment: Since the question is, "Writing variables to file in bash", it would be helpful (to those who end up here when searching for "write variable to file") if your example included writing the variable's value to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Using `printf` in any shell script is uncommon, just use `echo` with the `-e` option.
It allows you to use ANSI C metacharacters, like `\t` or `\n`. The `\n` at the end however isn't necessary, as `echo` will add one itself.

```
echo -e "template(${DATE}\t${HOST}\t${PRIORITY}\t${MSG})" >> file.txt
```

The problem with what you've written is, that ANSI C metacharacters, like `\t` can only be used in the *first* parameter to `printf`.

So it would have to be something like:

```
printf 'template(%s\t%s\t%s\t%s)\n' ${DATE} ${HOST} ${PRIORITY} ${MSG} >> file.txt
```

But I hope we both agree, that this is very hard on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several escaping issues and the power of `printf` has not been used, try

```
printf 'template(%s\t%s\t%s\t%s)\n' "${DATE}" "${HOST}" "${PRIORITY}" "${MSG}" >> file.txt
```

Reasons for this separate answer:

- The accepted answer does not fit the title of the question (see comment).
- The post with the right answer

  - contains wrong claims about `echo` vs `printf` as of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/467756/937632) and
  - is not robust against whitespace in the values.
- The edit queue is full at the moment.